# Newbie to jQuery and get function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get

I am completely new to jQuery.  I can't find any good documentation on the get function and was wondering if I could get some help.

I have an HTML page called me.html with just a single div called me.  I want to use the following page to get the contents within the div.  Even a google in the right direction would help.  Thanks so much

```
<head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <form id="form" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div id="me">
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Depends on where you want to load `#me` into. Seeing as how you mentioned `$.get` on your question title, I'm assuming you want to load the `div#me` from a different page? If so, then you're really looking for `$.load()`. [Click here for documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to use `get()`. This simple script should do it

```
<script>
  var contentsOfMe = $('#me').html();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I can't express how much you've helped.

Answer (score 2):

get is used for loading data from an url.  You seem to be wanting to get the contents of a div

as in `$("#me").text()`

Answer (score 0):

What about using the great documentation provided at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

EDIT. If you want to just get the text, use `var myText=$('#me').html();`, and if the html, use  `var myHtml=$('#me').html();`

Comment: This should be a comment. It's also not relevant to the question asked. OP didn't ask about making an ajax request, she's asking about selecting a div on the page and getting it's contents.

Comment: @xdumaine.  Agree.  I read the question about how to use jQuery's `get()`.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the documentation for the function get here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

But get is to perform an ajax request get on your server so I don't think that's what you need.

In jquery, most of the time you will "select" an element using jquery selector : `$("#id")`

This will select `$()`, this will say you are selecting an element using his id `$("#name_of_the_id")`.

Then, you will have an object which will represent the selected element.
If you want to get all the html inside this element do :

```
function getHtmlFromElementId(id)
{
  var element = $("#" + id);
  var html = element.html();
  return html;
}
```

Printing the return of this function will print all html code inside the element selected.

If you are seaching for a good tutorial on jquery, the w3schools' one is really good:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_examples.asp